# Convertir en json varias tablas desde una consulta en sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

Bueno no he podido lograr la conversión que necesito y me parece que por este lado me podría funcionar. Teniendo ya estas clases generadas con http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class ProductoConsultaJ
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class SubpartidaConsultaJ
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nodes")]
    public List<ProductoConsultaJ> nodes { get; set; }
}

public class PartidaConsultaJ
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nodes")]
    public List<SubpartidaConsultaJ> nodes { get; set; }
}

public class CapituloConsultaJ
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nodes")]
    public List<PartidaConsultaJ> nodes { get; set; }
}
```

y teniendo estas tablas relacionadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría guiarme como debo llenar las clases para generar este json?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de llenarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.ChapterCode, dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.DescriptionSpa, dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.DescriptionEng " + 
                        "FROM dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS INNER JOIN " + 
                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.ChapterCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.ChapterCode INNER JOIN " + 
                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.HeadingCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS.HeadingCode INNER JOIN " + 
                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_PRODUCTOS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS.SubHeadingCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_PRODUCTOS.SubheadingCode", con))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    List<CapituloConsultaJ> objListaCapitulos = new List<CapituloConsultaJ>();

                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        CapituloConsultaJ objCapitulo = new CapituloConsultaJ();

                                        objCapitulo.Text = reader["DescriptionSpa"].ToString();
                                        objListaCapitulos.Add(objCapitulo);

                                        using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.ChapterCode, dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.DescriptionSpa, " +
                                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.DescriptionEng " +
                                        " FROM dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS INNER JOIN " +
                                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_CAPITULOS.ChapterCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.ChapterCode INNER JOIN " +
                                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.HeadingCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS.HeadingCode INNER JOIN " +
                                        "dbo.TEMPORAL_PRODUCTOS ON dbo.TEMPORAL_SUBPARTIDAS.SubHeadingCode = dbo.TEMPORAL_PRODUCTOS.SubheadingCode " + 
                                        "where TEMPORAL_PARTIDAS.ChapterCode = '" + reader["ChapterCode"].ToString() + "'", con))
                                        {
                                            using (SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
                                            {
                                                List<PartidaConsultaJ> objListaPartidas = new List<PartidaConsultaJ>();
                                                while (reader2.Read())
                                                {
                                                    PartidaConsultaJ objPartida = new PartidaConsultaJ();
                                                    objPartida.Text = reader2["DescriptionSpa"].ToString();
                                                   objCapitulo.nodes.Add(objPartida);



                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    getValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objListaCapitulos);
                                }    
                }
```

Y me genera error en objCapitulo.nodes.Add(objPartida); Como se debe llenar ese objeto. Gracias

Comment: Que error genera?

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de SQL estás usando?

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta objCapitulo.nodes.Add(objPartida) me dice que Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Y la versión de SQL server que utilizo es la 2016 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error de Referencia a objeto no establecida que comentas se debe a que no has inicializado la colección "nodes" y por lo tanto es null. Puedes cambiar la línea donde instancias objCapitulo por
`CapituloConsultaJ objCapitulo = new CapituloConsultaJ() { nodes = new List<PartidaConsultaJ>()};` , o puedes añadir un constructor a cada clase e inicializar en él las colecciones. O según la versión c# que estés usando usar el inicializador en la propiedad 
`public List<PartidaConsultaJ> nodes { get; set; } = new List<PartidaConsultaJ>();`